# AWS EC2 instance traffic spike on port 80

Tags: attacks

We received an "abuse report" from AWS indicating we may have experienced a DDOS attack. From what i could see there was definitely some spikes in the last two days. According to AWS it was through port 80 (HTTP/WEB) which we need. To be honest this is not very frequent. However i just wanted to take in some suggestions from the community on what are some should / could do's in this situation?

Comment: Not enough info. How many requests during how long a time frame? What where they querying? Were those legitimate resources, or probing non-existing locations? Can you see their source IPs? How does their geolocation compare to your usual target demographic? *Details matter.*

Comment: What do you ***want*** to do?